# Returning function value

Tags: javascript, node.js, watson-conversation

I have a function updateMessage, that performs a check up on the values of `payload`, calls a weather API through the function `checkWeather()` and appends the result of that API to the `finalResponse` variable.

However, I keep getting `undefined` when I call `checkWeather()` inside the `updateMessage` function.

The `checkWeather` function is working fine, but for some reason its out scope when I try to return its value.

```
function updateMessage(payload, response) {
    //Set var to JSON value
    let finalResponse = response.output.text;

    // Set var to function and return it
    weatherData = checkWeather(appCity, appST);

    return finalResponse.push(weatherData);
}
function checkWeather( ... )
```

The full code can be accessed in this gist [here](https://gist.github.com/agomez314/c50c5f5c5270e7457e1791cdccc4c813)

Comment: Maybe `checkWearher` is async for some reason?

Comment: `Array.prototype.push` doesn't return a reference to the array the method was called on, it might be the same here

Answer (score 1):

If you change return `finalResponse.push(weatherData);` statement with

```
finalResponse.push(weatherData);
return finalResponse
```

It will work...